# c# MVC hide header buttons conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my `_Layout.cshtml` I have the following code which will not show the buttons if the user's role is `UserType1`

```
     @if (!(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("UserType1")))
     { 
       <li><a href="../St/Index">Static</a> </li>
       <li><a href="../St/Clients">Clients</a> </li>
     }
```

I was wondering if there is a better or best practice way of doing this. Please note that I am putting this code in my `_Layout.cshtml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems fine. Some people (like me) might prefer to bring this a step further and wrap this check in a custom HTML helper though in order to be able to unit test the condition:

```
@if (Html.ShouldShowButtons())
{ 
    <li><a href="../St/Index">Static</a> </li>
    <li><a href="../St/Clients">Clients</a> </li>
}
```

and the implementation of the helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static bool ShouldShowButtons(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("UserType1");
    }
}
```

As an alternative you could implement more complex logic using child actions:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MenuButtons", "Menu");}
```

You would then have a corresponding controller action which is checking whether the user is in the required role and render a partial view with the markup.

Comment: Thanks Darin, can you share with me how a helper like the one you mentioned would work. Or, can you point me to where I can find out more information on such a helper.

Comment: Sure, answer updated with an example of how the custom helper might look like.